# matplotlibで描画した図の軸ラベルが表示されない

Tags: python, python3, matplotlib

[サンプルコード](https://qiita.com/damyarou/items/e5e4c932915f5d74bfb2)をコピペし,matplotlibで図を描画したのですが，下図のように左の図のx軸，y軸のラベルと判例が表示されません．トリミングされてるのかと思いplt.show()の前に

```
plt.tight_layout()
```

を追加したり

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6), facecolor='w')
```

のfigsizeを(12,6)に変えてみたりしたのですが上手くいきません．
何か対処法がわかる方がいれば教えていただきたいです．

実行環境はpython3.5 (on anaconda), matplotlibはver.2.1.0です．

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

この問題は、リンクなさっているサンプルコードで既に対応されています。`plt.show()` で出てくるウィンドウではなく、保存された画像の方ではラベルが表示されています。

### なぜ？

今回のコードでは、画像を保存する際以下のように追加で設定を行っています（[元のコード](https://qiita.com/damyarou/items/e5e4c932915f5d74bfb2#3-%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A9%E3%83%A0%E5%85%A8%E6%96%87)より引用します）。

```
plt.savefig(fnameF, dpi=200, bbox_inches="tight", pad_inches=0.1)
```

特に `bbox_inches="tight"` が効いており、レイアウトが変わってラベルが表示されます。

Comment: @nekketsuuuさん，保存された画像ファイルを確認したところ，正しくラベルが入っておりました．plt.show()は時々見切れることがあるのですね．回答ありがとうございました．

Comment: 正確には、`plt.show()` 時点での設定と異なり `plt.savefig()` では追加で設定をしているため、出力が変わっています。